# Value of field author for System Account and FBA

Tags: forms-authentication, login, claims, membership, system-account

I´m in a process of upgrading a sharepoint 2010 farm to 2013 -> 2016 -> 2019.

I 2019, when testing a custom webpart to get the value of field "author" from a item created by the System Account, like

SPListItem item = ...;

... = item["Author"].toString();

it returns:

7;#spFarmAcc,#i:0#.f|ldapmember|spframacc,#,#,#spFarmAcc

I was expcting just :
7;#spFarmAcc

Seems like thie field join a lot of info into it.

If I query at web.alluseres, it is just like 7;#spFarmAcc.

So, what is this all information, how it get there ?
Some article about this subject ?

Thanks